# .htaccess - Dynamic Redirect virtual folder to file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=44]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=44]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1
```

It redirects `site.com/folder to site.com/index.php?id=folder`

I would like it to redirect `site.com/folder/?lol=some to site.com/index.php?id=folder&lol=some`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QSA flag. Change your last RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```